# Combine arguments of different classes

Tags: r

Let me elaborate with an example:

```
mystr = "foo"
intvector = c(1,2,3,4,5)
trial1 = c(mystr,intvector)
sapply(trial1,class)

trial2 = mat.or.vec(1+length(intvector),1)
trial2[1] = mystr
trial2[2:length(trial2)] = intvector
sapply(trial2,class)
```

Both return

```
        foo           1           2           3           4           5 
"character" "character" "character" "character" "character" "character"
```

As you can see, R converts/casts the `numeric` type to `character` type for me, which is not what I want. Thanks :)

EDIT: I will use the result to append (`rbind`) it directly to a `data.frame`, which initially will be empty, so the column classes will not yet be defined.

Comment: This is expected behavior, because a vector can be of only one class. Using a `data.frame` (as you noted in the answer below) with one row is how I would do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this should work. If anyone finds a better solution, without using lists, please let me know.

```
trial3 = data.frame(I(mystr), t(intvector))
sapply(trial3,class)
```

Produces:

```
    mystr        X1        X2        X3        X4        X5 
   "AsIs" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric"
```

Note that we have to wrap mystr in `I` and transpose the intvector in order for this to work.

Comment: Right, that does not give what the OP was asking for. He wanted one column with varying classes. Not possible.

Comment: @DWin, did you mean one "row" (because Grega wants to `rbind`). I think this solution is just fine. Also, notice that OP is also the author of this answer. :)

Answer (score 3):

There is no way you can avoid if you do not use lists. The `c` function will coerce to "lowest common denominator", which in this case is "character':

```
 trial1 = list(mystr,intvector)
 sapply(trial1,class)
#[1] "character" "numeric"
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. I should have stated that I was trying to find an answer without using lists, since I will append the result directly to a data.frame (which can also be empty and so the column classes are not defined).

Comment: You have no hope of success. The columns of a dataframe need to all be if the same mode and class.

Comment: The columns of a dataframe don't need to be the same mode and class. Only all the elements within one column need to be of the same mode and class.

Comment: Of course, they don't, and are not in general. But all of the elements in one column need to be the same.